# Convert a csv.DictReader object to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

A csv file `names.csv` has content:

```
first_name last_name
Baked Beans
Lovely Spam
Wonderful Spam
```

I would like to read it into a list of dictionaries, with the first row containing the keys:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Baked Beans
Lovely Spam
Wonderful Spam
```

But is the type of `reader` `csv.DictReader`? 
How can I convert `reader` into a list of dictionaries?
Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

```
import csv
with open("in.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=" ")
    print(list(reader))
[{'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'}, {'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'}, {'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'}]
```

If the delimiter is not actually a `,` you need to specify `" "` or whatever it is.

Just to clear any confusion, the code works fine for python3.6 also, the only difference is that using [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) gives [Orderdicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) by default:

```
In [1]: import csv
   ...: with open("in.csv") as csvfile:
   ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=" ")
   ...:     print(list(reader))
   ...:     
[OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Baked'), ('last_name', 'Beans')]), OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Lovely'), ('last_name', 'Spam')]), OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Wonderful'), ('last_name', 'Spam')])]
```

You can access keys exactly the same, an `OrderedDict` just keeps key insertion order:

```
In [2]: import csv
   ...: with open("in.csv") as csvfile:
   ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=" ")
   ...:     for dct in reader:
   ...:         print(f"{dct['first_name']} {dct['last_name']}")
   ...:         
   ...:     
Baked Beans
Lovely Spam
Wonderful Spam
```

Which py3.6 actually does too, so if for some reason you really want a dict:

```
In [5]: import csv
   ...: with open("in.csv") as csvfile:
   ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=" ")
   ...:     for dct in map(dict, reader):
   ...:         print(dct)
   ...:         print(f"{dct['first_name']} {dct['last_name']}")
   ...:         
   ...:     
{'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'}
Baked Beans
{'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'}
Lovely Spam
{'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'}
Wonderful Spam
```

The ordering retention on insertion in py3.6 is an *implementation detail* and may change, but if enough of us use it, it may just have to stay :)

Comment: Not correct with Python 3.6, which should use `print([dict(d) for d in reader])`

Comment: @MattFletcher,  it works fine in py3.6,  what is not working for you? Is it because you see `OrderedDict's`?

Comment: Yes, and therefore can't iterate over it properly. I'm not a Python master so I may be missing something massive, but I read that they way it worked had been changed in py3.6 - can't for the life of me find the SO thread...

Comment: @MattFletcher, I added a little more to the answer, an OrderDict is, for all intents and purposes a dictionary, it just maintains the insertion order, so for your csv, you would see columns/keys in the same order as they appear in your file.

Comment: Gotcha. Blame my own stupidity then ;) thanks for clarifying too, I've been banging my head with `Dict` vs `OrderedDict`!

Comment: @MattFletcher, no worries, for py < 3.6, dict ordering is random, so you needed an OrderedDict specifically, if you wanted to maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 26):

Use `list()`:

```
print(list(reader))
```

Demo:

```
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=" ")
...     print(list(reader))
... 
[{'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'}, {'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'}, {'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'}]
```

Comment: What if the csv file has many columns? How will it form dictionary,or lists

Comment: @HNSingh The dictionaries within the list will just be longer. In the example above, the only columns are `first_name` and `last_name`.

Answer (score 10):

Create function

```
import csv


def csv_to_dict(filename):
    result_list=[]
    with open(filename) as file_obj:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=delimiter)
        for row in reader:
            result_list.append(dict(row))
    return result_list
```

and use it:

```
list_of_dicts = csv_to_dict('names.csv')
```

Answer (score 6):

The csv.DictReader creates a dictreader object as noted in the title. This object is only useable while the file is open and cant be sliced.

To convert the object to a list as per the title....

```
list_of_dicts = list(your_dictreader_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    dict_item = list(map(dict, reader))
    result = dict((key, dict_item[0][result[key]]) for key in result.keys())
```

Comment: This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?