# How to convert a csv file with date index and tuple of int values to dict suitable for plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a sample of the csv data:

```
Timestamp,Systolic,Diastolic,Pulse
201711051037,135,81,62
201711061614,121,74,60
201711150922,129,74,70
201711170901,135,80,65
```

I am using Python 3.6.8 and this script to create a dict:

```
from csv import DictReader as dict_reader

d = dict()

with open(CSV_FILE, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = dict_reader(csvfile)
    ts, sy, dia, p = next(reader)
    for r in reader:
        d[r[ts]] = int(r[sy]), int(r[dia]), int(r[p])
```

The result is:

{'201711051037': (135, 81, 62), '201711061614': (121, 74, 60), '201711150922': (129, 74, 70), '201711170901': (135, 80, 65)}

I would like to convert the result into a form that can be used with Matplotlib plot.  Possibly something like:

```
Timestamp = [201711051037, 201711061614, 201711150922, 201711170901]
Systolic = [135, 121, 129, 135]
Diastolic = [81, 74, 74, 80]
Pulse = [62, 60, 70, 65]
```

In order to create a line plot with Matplotlib and use fills and other features, I believe the data needs to be in separate lists.  I have tried different things like:

```
index = list(d.keys())
data = list(d.values())
sy = [data[i][j] for i in data for j in data]
```

And also looked at these similar questions:

[Make dicts read from a csv file ordered dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434296/make-dicts-read-from-a-csv-file-ordered-dicts)

[Python matplotlib plot dict with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044792/python-matplotlib-plot-dict-with-multiple-values)

[Plotting a dictionary with multiple values per key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255677/plotting-a-dictionary-with-multiple-values-per-key)

However, I am stuck at this point.  Any hints or directions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to create the intermidiate dictionary? Why not directly put the data into lists?

Comment: @DobromirM, By using csv reader and slices to create the lists directly? That sounds like it will work, I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with what you want the output to look like:

```
Timestamp = [201711051037, 201711061614, 201711150922, 201711170901]
Systolic = [135, 121, 129, 135]
Diastolic = [81, 74, 74, 80]
Pulse = [62, 60, 70, 65]
```

You can get these from:

```
Timestamp = [int(stamp) for stamp in d.keys()]
Systolic = [value[0] for value in d.values()]
Diastolic = [value[1] for value in d.values()]
Pulse = [value[2] for value in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in alternative solution, you can use `*` to unpack the dictionary values and then use `zip` to get three different lists. Here I am using `map` to convert the output into lists, which is what you want.

```
dic = {'201711051037': (135, 81, 62), '201711061614': (121, 74, 60), 
       '201711150922': (129, 74, 70), '201711170901': (135, 80, 65)}


Timestamp = list(map(int, dic.keys()))
Systolic, Diastolic, Pulse = map(list, zip(*dic.values())) 

print (Timestamp)
print (Systolic)
print (Diastolic)
print (Pulse)

# [201711051037, 201711061614, 201711150922, 201711170901]
# [135, 121, 129, 135]
# [81, 74, 74, 80]
# [62, 60, 70, 65]
```

Moreover, if you have to just plot them, you don't need to convert the values into lists

```
Timestamp = list(map(int, dic.keys()))
Systolic, Diastolic, Pulse = zip(*dic.values())

plt.plot(Timestamp, Systolic, label='Systolic')
plt.plot(Timestamp, Diastolic, label='Diastolic')
plt.plot(Timestamp, Pulse, label='Pulse')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. These Python idioms are very clean. As a beginner programmer I am glad to have been introduced to them.