# How can I create a list of dictionaries from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, file

I want to create a "dictionary of dictionaries" for each row of the following csv file

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

So the idea is, that mydict["Alice"] should be {'AGATC': 2, 'AATG': 8, 'TATC': 3} etc.

I really do not understand the .reader and .DictReader functions sufficiently. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader
Because I am a newbie and cannot quite understand the docs. Do you have other 'easier' resources, that you can recommend?

First, I have to get the first column, i.e. names and put them as keys. How can I access that first column?

Second, I want to create a dictionary inside that name (as the value), with the keys being AGATC,AATG,TATC. Do you understand what I mean? Is that possible?

Edit, made progess:

```
# Open the CSV file and read its contents into memory.
with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
    # Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.
    # Establish dicts.
    mydict = {}
    for i in range(1, len(reader)):
        print(reader[i][0])
        mydict[reader[i][0]] = reader[i][1:]
    print(mydict)
```

Out:

```
{'Alice': ['2', '8', '3'], 'Bob': ['4', '1', '5'], 'Charlie': ['3', '2', '5']}
```

But how to implement nested dictionaries as described above?

Edit #3:

```
# Open the CSV file and read its contents into memory.
    with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
        reader = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
        # Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.
        # Establish dicts.
        mydict = {}
        for i in range(1, len(reader)):
            print(reader[i][0])
            mydict[reader[i][0]] = reader[i][1:]
        print(mydict)
        
        print(len(reader))
        dictlist = [dict() for x in range(1, len(reader))]
        #for i in range(1, len(reader))
        for i in range(1, len(reader)):
            dictlist[i-1] = dict(zip(reader[0][1:], mydict[reader[i][0]]))
        #dictionary = dict(zip(reader[0][1:], mydict[reader[1][0]]))
        print(dictlist)
```

Out:

```
[{'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'}, {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}, {'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}]
{'AGATC': 1, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}
```

So I solved it for myself:)

Comment: I think my real problem is that I do not understand the row ? How does that work? Is this defined anywhere? I am coming from C-Programming, so I am confused that the computer apparently knows what row is without me having implemented row.

Comment: `reader` is an iterable. `for row in reader` tells python that `row` is each element of that iterable as you are iterating over it. You _are_ telling the computer what `row` is. Does that help?

Comment: See example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432912/convert-a-csv-dictreader-object-to-a-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: https://overlaid.net/2016/02/04/convert-a-csv-to-a-dictionary-in-python/

Comment: Your solution marked "Solved it for myself." doesn't seem to include the names.

Comment: @RufusVS Yeah, you are right. It is just a list of dictionaries, when it should be a dictionary of dictionaries, so that I can have names as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you what you've asked for in terms of dict struture.

```py
import csv

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    mydict = {}
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    # Iterate through each line of the csv file
    for row in reader:
        # Create the dictionary structure as desired.
        # This uses a comprehension
        # Foreach item in the row get the key and the value except if the key
        # is 'name' (k != 'name')
        mydict[row['name']] = { k: v for k, v in row.items() if k != 'name' }
    print(mydict)
```

This will give you

```py
{
    'Alice': {'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},
    'Bob': {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},
    'Charlie': {'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}
}
```

There are plenty of videos and articles covering comprehensions on the net if you need more information on these.